# Packaging Mongo Database with my Desktop App

Tags: mongodb, cross-platform, desktop-application, packaging

I am not sure if it is possible or not. I am building a desktop application which will use MongoDatabse. I am packing my application in `.deb` and in `.exe` but I also want to pack MongoDB with it. So one does not need to manually download the mongo database to use my app.

99.9% times the system on which my application will be installed will be a normal system with no database. Something like desktop ERP.

How can I solve this or If it's not possible, is it possible to auto-download and install Mongo DB by some script on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible to ship MongoDB with your application. In the [official MongoDB website](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) you can select the Package type to download, which can be `zip` for Windows or `tgz` for Debian. After unpacking them, you can start the Mongo daemon using the command line `mongod` and add the `--port` and `--dbpath` parameters. E.g.: `mongod --port 27080 --dbpath C:\MyApp\db`.

I understand where you come from, as most DBs require an installation/configuration before using them. Although MongoDB has installers, it's possible to setup a working instance by just extracting the compressed files from the downloads page.